# Не работает повторная сортировка ArrayList с помощью Comparator

Tags: java, сортировка, arraylist, compare

Есть в классе Cat

```
static List<Cat> listcat = new ArrayList<>();
```

Есть метод sortByWeight который принимает строку (в моем случае я предлагаю up, или down) а в switch уже выбираю ту или иную сортировку.

```
public static void sortByWeight(String desc){
    desc = desc.toLowerCase();
    switch ( desc ){
        case "up":{
            Collections.sort(listcat, new CatWeightComparatorUp());
        }
        case "down":{
            Collections.sort(listcat, new CatWeightComparatorDown());
        }
    }
}
```

Далее сортирую свой лист один раз, вывожу его, а затем сортирую наоборот и вывожу. В итоге получается первая сортировка работает, а вторая выводит тоже самое что и первая.

```
sortByWeight("down"); // Сортировка down

System.out.print("\ndown");
showList(); // Показываю список после сортировки down

sortByWeight("up"); // Сортировка up

System.out.print("\nup");
showList(); // Показываю список после сортировки up
```

Метод showList реализован так:

```
public static void showList(){
    Iterator<Cat> iter = listcat.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iter.next());
    }
}
```

Ну и понятное дело класс компаратор:

```
package lesson11.cats;

import java.util.Comparator;

class CatWeightComparatorDown implements Comparator<Cat>{

    public int compare(Cat a, Cat b){
        if(a.getWeight() > b.getWeight()){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
class CatWeightComparatorUp implements Comparator<Cat>{

public int compare(Cat b, Cat a){
    if(a.getWeight() < b.getWeight()){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
}
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь и замечания по реализации. 
Основные требования к задаче:

> Считать данные и создать коллекцию ArrayList.
>   Отсортировать элементы коллекции по весу с
>   использованием интерфейса Comparable.

Для удобства ссылка на [GitHub](https://github.com/LoGwi-N/part_two/tree/master/src/lesson11/cats)

Comment: странная логика в compare(). Было бы гораздо проще сделать что-то типа `return (a.getWeight() - b.getWeight())` для одного случая и `return (b.getWeight() - a.getWeight())` для другого. Всё просто и прозрачно, должно заработать

Comment: Попробовал, все тоже самое. Ошибка где-то в другом месте. Добавил в  CatWeightComparatorDown вывод "зашел в down" а в Up  наоборот. При запуске сортировок выводит вот что. Зашел в Down
Зашел в Down
Зашел в Down
Зашел в Down
Зашел в Down
Зашел в Down
Зашел в Down
Зашел в Down
Зашел в Down
Зашел в Down
Зашел в Down

Зашел в Up
Зашел в Up
Зашел в Up
Зашел в Up
Зашел в Up
Зашел в Down
Зашел в Down
Зашел в Down
Зашел в Down
Зашел в Down

Comment: в свиче не хватает `break`ов. Когда вы вводите "up" он сортирует сначала по возрастанию, а потом проваливается и сортирует по убыванию.

Comment: Спасибо) Разобрался наконец, забыл про break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Barmaley уже указал вам на ошибку, а я хочу вам посоветовать несколько упростить код - компаратор для сравнения по одному атрибуту можно сделать, используя [Comparator.comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Collections.sort(listcat, Comparator.comparing(Cat::getWeight)); //по возрастанию
Collections.sort(listcat, Comparator.comparing(Cat::getWeight).reversed()); //по убыванию
```

Comment: Ваш метод обязательно попробую. А в целом проблема была в отсутствии брейков в свичах.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка здесь (см. комментарий к декларации метода):

```
class CatWeightComparatorUp implements Comparator<Cat>{

public int compare(Cat b, Cat a){ //перепутаны аргументы местами
    if(a.getWeight() < b.getWeight()){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Я уже чего только не делал, назад менял, и знак в if, и возвращал значения наоборот